# Android - WebView not displaying mobile version of website

Tags: android, mobile, webview

I'm loading a URL into an Android WebView.The website that I'm loading is provided by a 3rd party (it's outside of my control).
The URL is a website that displays a mobile version of the website if it detects that it's loading on a mobile device.
The site displays the mobile version on a Nexus 5 emulator, using the following code, but on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S3), the mobile version isn't displayed. Interestingly, if I view the same URL using the Chrome browser on my device, it works fine.

```
package com.mydomain.mypackage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //works for emulator
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for x86 Build/MASTER; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile Safari/537.36";

        myView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
        myView.loadUrl("http://myurl.com/myHomePage");
    }
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me. I'd expect that the website is using the user agent string to detect whether the URL is being loaded on mobile device. As I've hardcoded this,  I'd expect that it would always display the mobile website on my Samsung S3. Any ideas what's going on or how I can get this working?

**UPDATE:** Adding this didn't work:

```
myView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: What happens if you try to load this URL in your browser using S3?

Comment: if you find a solution kindly post it. I am also having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead use getDefaultUserAgent(Context context) or getUserAgentString()? I think this would work instead of the hardcode and perhaps solve the problem with device compatibility issues.

More info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)

Comment: Thanks Richard, I've already tried using getUserAgentString and it didn't work. The 'getDefaultUserAgent' is a useful suggestion however it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Mine was solved when I overrode shouldOverrideUrlLoading when setting webViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```